# PHP replace string between curly brackets with array element value

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've a body of content that is read in and it contains numerous strings like `{{some_text}}` and what I'm trying to do is to find all these occurances and replace them with another value from an array for example `$text["some_text"]`.

I've tried using preg_replace but not sure how I go about taking the found text between the brackets and use it in the replace value.

```
$body = "This is a body of {{some_text}} text from a book.";
$text["some_text"] = "really cool";
$parsedBody = preg_replace("\[{].*[}]/U", $text[""], $body);
```

As you can see I'm trying to get the `some_text`text out of the string and use it to call an element from an array, this example is very basic as there `$body`value is vastly larger and `$text`has a couple hundred elements too it.

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Or maybe you should just invest in a real template library.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the suggestion, I'll look at `preg_replace_callback` now, for what I need it is overkill to use a templagte library.

Comment: An other way consists to use preg_split with the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE option, to map the array and replace odd items (use an associative array) and to implode.

Comment: @Barmar, took your advice after my custom code got too complex, using twig via composer now, makes life much easier, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` and use the capturing group `([^}]+)` to find an index in the array `$text`:

```
$repl = preg_replace_callback('/{{([^}]+)}}/', function ($m) use ($text) {
            return $text[$m[1]]; }, $body);
//=> This is a body of really cool text from a book.
```

The `use ($text)` statement passes the reference of `$text` to the anonymous `function`.

Answer (score 4):

How about doing it the other way around - instead of finding all `{{...}}` placeholders and looking up their values, iterate through all values and replace placeholders that match like this:

```php
foreach ($text as $key => $value) {
    $placeholder = sprintf('{{%s}}', $key);
    $body        = str_replace($placeholder, $value, $body);
}
```

You can even wrap it into a function:

```php
function populatePlaceholders($body, array $vars)
{
    foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
        $placeholder = sprintf('{{%s}}', $key);
        $body        = str_replace($placeholder, $value, $body);
    }

    return $body;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, using your array as is:

```
$result = str_replace(array_map(function($v){return '{{'.$v.'}}';}, array_keys($text)),
                      $text, $body);
```

Or if your array is like `$text['{{some_text}}']` then simply:

```
$result = str_replace(array_keys($text), $text, $body);
```